# Celery flower Persistent data not restored

Tags: celery, flower

Environment:

- Python: 3.4
- Celery: 4.1.0
- Flower: 0.9.0
- Centos: 7.0

  `--persistent` flag is used. Celery version v4.1.0.

If I create a couple of tasks, they run as expected.

After I send a SIGINT:

```
[D 150923 14:43:09 events:96] Saving state to 'flower'...
[D 150923 14:43:09 events:97] <State: events=54 tasks=4>
```

The DB file 'flower' clearly contains the correct data. When I start flower again:

```
[D 150923 14:47:35 events:76] Loading state from 'flower'...
[D 150923 14:47:35 events:80] <State: events=0 tasks=0>
```

If I run Python and load the file with shelve:

```
> f['events']
> <State: events=0 tasks=0>
```

So, something isn't working correctly when shelve reads the file.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It looks like celery's `State.__repr__` method prints the event_count and task_count attribtues.

From https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/v4.1.0/celery/events/state.py

```
R_STATE = '<State: events={0.event_count} tasks={0.task_count}>'
....
def __repr__(self):
    return R_STATE.format(self)
```

However, event_count and task_count are not included in the pickled form, which means those attributes will default to 0 when the contents are read back from the db. From the same file:

```
def __reduce__(self):
    return self.__class__, (
        self.event_callback, self.workers, self.tasks, None,
        self.max_workers_in_memory, self.max_tasks_in_memory,
        self.on_node_join, self.on_node_leave,
        _serialize_Task_WeakSet_Mapping(self.tasks_by_type),
        _serialize_Task_WeakSet_Mapping(self.tasks_by_worker),
)
```

You'll notice that when persistence is enabled, the tasks listed in flowers "Tasks" view will persist across flower restarts, which shows the state is being read in correctly from the db.